# Before adding a language, I want to check if it is in the list from the future file. If it is, delete it, then add all from a future file

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

My logic
1)
Before adding a language:
I take the first language from the Future File and go to the site page, which also has a list of languages.
If the language is present in the Sheet, I select it (using the checkbox) and delete it.
Next, I go to the next language from the Future list, check again and delete it on the page.
I perform this loop until all languages ​​are removed from the list of future pages. The file will not be removed from the list of web pages.

2. Then I add these same languages ​​to the lists from the future file.

I thought of this logic, but my code is in a hurry to the remote language on the web page.
I've been racking my brain for two days, I can't find a solution.

My future file:

When Admin add multiple language from datatable

```
|Name|
|German|
|Turkish|
|Spain|
```

My Steps:

```
public void adminAddMultipleLanguageFromDatatable(io.cucumber.datatable.DataTable dataTable) throws InterruptedException {
    List<WebElement> Languages = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//table/tbody/tr/td[2]"));
    List<Map<String, String>> data = dataTable.asMaps();
    for (Map<String, String> datas : data) {
        for (int i = 0; i < Languages.size(); i++) {
            String dataName = datas.get("Name");
            String name = Languages.get(i).getText();
            if (dataName.equalsIgnoreCase(name)) {
                WebElement checkBox = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table/tbody/tr[" + (i + 1) + "]/td[1]"));
                click(checkBox);
                click(addLanguagePage.languageDelBtn);
                WebElement mes = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='message warning fadable']"));
                String m = "Successfully Deleted\n" + "Close";
                String m1 = mes.getText();
                Assert.assertEquals(m, m1);
            }
            click(addLanguagePage.languageAddBtn);
            sendText(datas.get("Name"), addLanguagePage.languageNameOption);
            click(addLanguagePage.languageSaveBtn);
            WebElement m2 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='message success fadable']"));
            String mm2 = m2.getText();
            String expecct = "Successfully Saved\n" + "Close";
            Assert.assertEquals(expecct, mm2);
        }
    }
}
```

Where is the issue?

https://ltdfoto.ru/image/BZm5Lh
[Language Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n8RPO.png)

Comment: You haven't described what the issue is. You also haven't given us code that we can run on our own so I'm not sure what you expect us to be able to do with the little bit of info you've provided. You need to describe more clearly what the scenario is supposed to be doing... step by step instructions in English text (not code) then describe what the current code is doing that is wrong and what the expected behavior is.

Comment: changed, Im sorry

Comment: You are still missing a LOT of info. 1. You refer to "the Sheet" but don't indicate what that is... is it the Future File or something on the webpage or something else? 2. "If the language is present in the Sheet ... you delete it"... delete it from what? The Future File, the web page, or something else? 3. What is the "list of future pages"? 4. "The file will not be removed..." What file? 5. "list of web pages" What list of web pages? 6. "Then I add these same languages to the list from the future file" What "same languages"? What "lists from the future file"?

Comment: Maybe it would be better if you described the overall goal of this code rather than describing your current approach. Maybe something like, "I navigate to the page and remove all languages found in the Future File." or something like that. I don't know if that's correct but describe what the expected result is after this code runs.

Comment: I go to the "Languages" page.
Then I check whether the language is present in the list “above in the picture” from my future file (future file is my scenario in which all the code should be run, what is written inside the future file is above before my code, this future file is used by QA Engeneer).

Comment: what I expect:
I want my code to first check whether all my languages ​​from the future file are present in that list on the web page (which is in the picture above). And If present (if the language from the future file is equal to the language from the web page), then remove these languages ​​from the list on the page (for this I used a for loop). Then the loop returns to the list of languages ​​that I specified in the future file. then I added these languages ​​to the page one by one

Comment: Right now my code only runs when the loop finds one language from the web page's list and the loop stops.

Overall I need to do a test of the languages ​​page.
Adding a language.
and for this I use the script

Comment: I hope it's clear now. )))

Comment: You keep referring to pictures but there are no pictures anywhere

Comment: I'm still confused about the goal of the scenario. What are you trying to test? Are you trying to test that all of the languages in the Future File are on the page? Are you trying to select the languages on the page that are in the Future File???

Comment: What you are describing is that you remove all the languages from the page that are found in the Future File but then you add them all back??? I don't understand the point. Are you trying to test that you can add the specific languages in the Future File to the page but need to remove them if they already exist???

Comment: The goal of the scenario is to check the Page for adding and removing languages.
Duplicate languages ​​are not allowed on the page.
To do this, I used the script: First, check if the languages ​​from the future file and the list of languages ​​from the page match.

Comment: Using a loop, I go through all the languages ​​from the future file and check for compliance with the Page. if there is a language match, then I simply remove that language from the Page.

Comment: After all languages ​​have been removed from the Page.
I add languages ​​from the future file. (yes, these are the same languages ​​that I deleted)

Comment: I added link to the photo

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but could it be;

`if (name.equalsIgnoreCase(dataName))`

instead of

`if (dataName.equalsIgnoreCase(name))`

you are looking at language names in data, wouldnt be the other way around. sorry i am little confuse too =) just tried to help

Comment: same , Code execute only once. I cant find where the problem